# Why is racket macro's lambda not returning anything?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, dsl

I'm trying to make a basic journal entry language in racket for a class on DSLs (specifically beautiful racket, the training version).  I have a correct parser and reader, but I am having difficulty with my macros.  Below is my expander code.  I am trying to have my DSL be functional rather than imperative (I know I could have a global ledger value that I update, but it is not in the spirit of this project).

I have included the code for the important functions in this module.  A lot of them are based off of this tutorial: https://beautifulracket.com/bf/a-functional-expander.html

Right now, when I run my code on this text:

```
[1920-02-19<equipment-20000><cash-10000,stock-10000>]
[2020-12-20<insurance-500><cash-500>]
```

I get this output from my display calls:

```
(#<date 1920-02-19> debits credits)()(#<date 2020-12-20> debits credits)#<void>#<void>
```

It looks like my lambda is not returning the updated ledger in my journal-entry macro.  My knowledge isn't great when it comes to Racket, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Any tips?

---

```
(define (fold-funcs apl ac-funcs)
  (for/fold ([current-apl apl])
            ([ac-func (in-list ac-funcs)])
    (ac-func current-apl)
    (display current-apl)))

(define-macro (ac-line ENTRIES ...)
  #'(begin
      (define ledger empty)
      (set! ledger (fold-funcs ledger (list ENTRIES ...)))
      (display ledger)))
(provide ac-line)

(define-macro (journal-entry "[" INFO ... "]")
  #'(lambda (ledger)
      (define entry (list INFO ...))
      (define dt (first entry))
      (set! entry (rest entry))
      (define d (first entry))
      (set! entry (rest entry))
      (define c (first entry))
      (define e (list dt d c))
      (display e)
      (set! ledger (cons e ledger))
      ledger
      ))
(provide journal-entry)
```

Comment: The `for/fold` inside `fold-funcs` expects the last expression to return a value, I'm guessing it should be the result of calling `(ac-func current-apl)`. However, the `display` is causing it to return `#<void>`.

Comment: You might catch problems like this earlier if you tried out functions like `fold-funcs` separately from your language, to see whether they work the way they expect. Trying it out either in the REPL or in unit tests can be really helpful for this.

Comment: I edited my fold to just cons the macros together and that displays something in my main macro.  Thanks!  My racket knowledge is not there yet, so I'd forgotten about how returns worked.

Comment: @AlexKnauth with my current setup, I should just have all of these lambdas consed together.  Could I then iterate over the cons if wanted to call them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cons the macros together" or "these lambdas consed together". Could you give an example?

Comment: My fold-funcs takes in the parsed functions from the reader along with an empty list.  Right now, I have it do this:
`(cond
      [(equal? "d" ac-func) (cons ac-func current-apl)]
      [(equal? "c" ac-func) (cons ac-func current-apl)]
      [else (cons ac-func current-apl)])))`
So every function is just added to the list.  My end goal is to have "c" clear the list, which shouldn't be too hard now that I have a better idea of how return work, and "d" to display the current list.  For "d" i would want to run through ledger and actually output the journal-entry macros.